# HealthConnect Rate Limited request Quota has been exceeded

Tags: flutter, healthconnect, flutter-health

**So I am working on a project that uses health connect to display user health related data(Steps, Heart Rate...). But currently my app crashes with the following error sometimes:**

```
android.os.RemoteException: Request rejected. Rate limited request quota has been exceeded. Please wait until quota has replenished before making further requests.
```

I kind of understand this error in the case that I think I have exceeded the quota for the amount of API calls I can make, but is there any interface or something I can use to see this imposed limit for healthConnect?

Currently I am using the following health package for my flutter app: https://pub.dev/packages/health

I have also looked at the following resources:

https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect-guidelines/rate-limiting

And the only solution I saw was that to limit API calls, a technique called channelLog handling should be used, but in order to use that I need to make a call for getChangesToken(https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect/common-workflows/sync-data#pull-data), but I believe currently the flutter health package doesn't support that...

So currently is there just no way of taking into account this error currently for a flutter app using healthConnect?

I apologize for the convoluted post, but kind of just need help with getting a sense of direction!

**Any help would be very much appreciated!**

Comment: Did you have any update on this or should I contact directly the support email?

Comment: Probably just contact support, haven't really gotten any reply/progress on this yet

Comment: Tried that didn't work ( the one that answers you just gives the link to the documentation and after that It doesn't answer anymore lol )

Comment: @MarcoEdoardoDuma (or @Kam5678) did you have any luck with a solution please?

Comment: Sadly not, I have posted on the offiical github for the package and made it an issue:

https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/issues/787

But from what I understand from the documentation the only solution would be to make API calls and store the data in your database. And then only make API calls when  needed for new data. (I obviously haven't implemented this, but this is my thought process currently).

If functionality for channel logging could be added to the package, that would be the best though, and make it a bit easier for us.

Comment: I've done something similar,  I ask for all the days I need in one call, for each data type needed, also remember you needed a foreground service to avoid people "closing" your app and the call being closed , the database ( I've used Room ) It's where I keep 98% of the previous 30 days, the last two days are being called directly.